# Nsight Visual Studio 2010 skips kernel breakpoints, detects wrong driver version

Tags: cuda, nsight

I'm using the Nsight 3.0 plugin with Visual Studio 2010 and CUDA 5.0.35.  To debug, I select "Start Cuda Debugging" from the Nsight menu.  Breakpoints in the kernel are skipped and I can't step through the kernel either.  I also get the following warning:

[image]

I'm using an integrated graphics card for my computer graphics and a local Geforce GTX680 for running the code.  My current 314.22 driver is listed on the Nvidia website as the most current driver for this model of graphics card.  I successfully updated to the very latest beta version of the driver, 320.14, but the message still says that 314.22 is detected.  What's going on?

Comment: Try uninstalling the previous driver and doing a clean install (there is a "clean install" checkbox when installing the new driver).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that some bits and pieces of the old driver are still laying around, and Nsight VSE is detecting this.

In most cases, selecting the "clean install" checkbox when you are installing a windows driver should remove any of these old bits and pieces (e.g. registry entries, etc.) that may be confusing Nsight VSE.